# Alamofire not POSTing to PHP script

Tags: php, swift, post, get, alamofire

I am creating a swift application where I need to POST data to my own webserver.
At the moment, my swift code looks like this.

```
fileprivate class AlamofireHelper {
     static var Manager : Alamofire.SessionManager = {
        // Create the server trust policies
        let serverTrustPolicies: [String: ServerTrustPolicy] = [
            "192.168.1.243": .disableEvaluation
        ]
        // Create custom manager
        let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        configuration.httpAdditionalHeaders = Alamofire.SessionManager.defaultHTTPHeaders
        let man = Alamofire.SessionManager(
            configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default,
            serverTrustPolicyManager: ServerTrustPolicyManager(policies: serverTrustPolicies)
        )
        return man
    }()

}
class UploadHelper
{

    private var _postData = [String:Any]()
    private let almoHelper = AlamofireHelper.Manager
    init(username:String) {
        _postData["username"] = username
        print("Setup")
        submitRequest()
    }

    func submitRequest()
    {
        print("Data is: \(_postData)")
        almoHelper.request("http:/192.168.1.243/networkStorage", method: .post, parameters: _postData, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseString { (responce) in
            print("Responce: \(responce)")
        }
    }
}
```

PHP:

```
<?php
    echo "POST: " . var_dump($_POST) . "\n\n\n\n";
    echo "GET: " . var_dump($_GET);
?>
```

The only problem is, when I run the swift code `let helper = UploadHelper(username: iProgram)`, I get the below response from my PHP script:

```
Data: ["username": "iProgram"]
Responce: SUCCESS: array(0) {
}
POST: 



array(0) {
}
GET:
```

Why are my POST and GET variables empty? I understand that the GET is empty becase I am only sending POST data, but shouldnt the POST show somthing like "username = iProgrammer"?

Finaly, here is the HTTP request I captured from burp suit:

```
GET /networkStorage/ HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.243
Accept: */*
User-Agent: Network%20Storage/1 CFNetwork/808.2.16 Darwin/16.3.0
Accept-Language: en-gb
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: close
```

**Edit:**
For some reason, when I use the below code and change my PHP script to show the 'GET' variable, I can see the data which it should send.

```
almoHelper.request("http://192.168.1.243/networkStorage", method: .get, parameters: _postData).responseString { (myResponce) in
            let result = myResponce.result
            print("Result is: \(result.value!)")
        }
```

And here is the request I intercepted from burp suite:

```
GET /networkStorage/?username=iProgram HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.243
Accept: */*
User-Agent: Network%20Storage/1 CFNetwork/808.2.16 Darwin/16.3.0
Accept-Language: en-gb
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: close
```

Comment: Can you try to read raw post data with <?php $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input"); ?>

Comment: @PawelDubiel when I echo out the data from there, I get nothing printed at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, `var_dump` doesn't return anything, it does output result, so use

```
echo "POST: "; var_dump($_POST); echo "\n\n\n\n";
```

or

```
echo "POST: " . print_r($_POST, true) . "\n\n\n\n";
```

`GET /networkStorage/ HTTP/1.1` shows that you make GET request, not POST. In addition you have wrong encoding `JSONEncoding.defaul`. Try to change request code a little:

```
almoHelper.request("http:/192.168.1.243/networkStorage", method: .post, parameters: _postData, encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody).responseString { (responce) in
    print("Responce: \(responce)")
}
```

If this does not work, try changing the URL from `http:/192.168.1.243/networkStorage` to `http:/192.168.1.243/networkStorage/` or `http:/192.168.1.243/networkStorage/index.php`.
This might fix the issue when you send a request to `/networkStorage`, it sends a new request to `/networkStorage/` as shown in the captured data from burpsuit.

Answer (score 0):

> Why are my POST and GET variables empty? I understand that the GET is empty becase I am only sending POST data, but shouldnt the POST show somthing like "username = iProgrammer"?

No. `$_POST` is only populated for HTML form-like encoding, such as application/x-www-form-urlencoded or multipart/form-data. It looks like what you're sending is JSON, in which case you need to read the `php://input` stream to get to the data.

Comment: If you look at my comment to pawl, file_get_contents("php://input") does not work. It prints nothing.